# How to center div text elements with zero line height?

Tags: html, css

Good day, I have trouble with creating specific structure of html elements with css that looks as follows:

[image]

My tryings ended with this propose:

[image]

I tried to do it programmatically, but always when I will set line-height css property to null between number and string, naturally whole content of div is pushed more up, and I can´t get it directly to middle. Even with pixel pushing it can be pain and not exact.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>


<style>
.circle
  {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red; 
   -moz-border-radius: 50px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 50px; 
   border-radius: 50px;
  }
</style>

<body>

<div style="margin-left:100px;">
<div align="center" class="circle">
<h1>9</h1>
<p>LEVEL</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to use any margins or height properties, but without positive result. This is my problem how look now:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to repair it programmatically? (any other similar questions didn´t help me, thanks for your time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markup:

```
<div class="level-container">
  <span class="number">9</span>
  <span class="level">level</span>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.level-container {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;

  .number,
  .level {
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 20px;
  }

  .number {
    font-size: 60px;
  }

  .level {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

Similar to Michael's solution, but my demo makes the content inside the container have `line-height: 0;`

[Demo](http://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/gmMpjp?editors=1100)

Comment: thank you for your answer with line-height: 0 ... this is useful for me, I will remember your solution, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You can use `line-height: 1` so that every element's line-height matches it's font-size, remove the default margins from the `h1` and `p`, then use flexbox to vertically and horizontally center the contents in the circle.

The `align` attribute is deprecated btw. You should center things using CSS, not HTML.

```css
* {margin:0;}
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:100px;">
  <div class="circle">
    <h1>9</h1>
    <p>LEVEL</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hahaha :D .. I would never make this on my own like this.. ok thank you.. thats correct answer for me